# Format horizontal axis for Google Charts Timelines?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

According to the [options available for the Timelines Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#Configuration_Options), there is no way to customize the horizontal axis (it is generated based on the date(time) objects you pass through the DataTabe). After many, many hours of Googling, I discovered you can customize it to a limited extent. Unfortunately, it still doesn't accomplish what I need. For example, you can set the min/maxValue of hAxis

```
hAxis: {
    maxValue: new Date("2018-06-05T24:00:00"), 
    minValue: new Date("2018-06-05T00:00:00")
}
```

[image]

or set the format

```
format: "h\naa"
```

[image]

However, I haven't found a way to remove the "minor" (non-bold) text without adding an event listener on 'ready' and setting the display style to none for the specific elements I wish to hide

```
function onReady() {
    var siblings = getNextElementSiblings(document.getElementById("defs"));

    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
        var sibling = siblings[i]; // g

        for (var j = 0; j < sibling.children.length; j++) {
            var child = sibling.children[j];

            if (child.tagName.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                if (!isNaN(child.textContent)) {
                    if (child.textContent != 12) {
                        child.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there a better (perhaps documented) way to do this?